# Access hosts in different sites

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I want to connect different hosts that are in different sites in EC2, in a way that they can communicate with each other. I know that there is VPC and it is used when you want to use IP sec tunnels. I don't need tunnels. I just want that the hosts in different sites can communicate with each other. I want to send data with `scp` or simply go the another host and launch a command (eg, ssh another_host "ls -la" ).

Should I use VPC? Is there any other inexpensive alternative?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to know that you are already using VPC, everytime you launch an instance it's started in a VPC. If you didn't configure anything, it's launched in a default VPC - each region has one.

Secondly, VPC itslef is free. You need to pay for only resources you connect to a VPC and for VPN connections.

Also we need to clarify what do you mean by the "site" term.

- If it's just a separate EC2 instance - you just need to launch all of them in one and the same VPC and private IP will be assigned to each of them.
  For more information see the following web page:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/GettingStartedGuide/getting-started-launch-instance.html

- If you mean that your instances are located in separate regions, you would have to connect them using VPN. More information here:

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/5472675506466066

If you have more questions, please let me know.

Regards,
Vlad,
CloudBerry Lab